# How do I compute the galactic cooridinates of the Earth for a given date?

Tags: astronomy, coordinate-systems

The question is simple enough, but I wasn't able to find any tools online. Does anyone know of one, or a simple formula?

Comment: The galactic x,y,z coordinates are defined such that the origin is at the galactic centre and the Sun is along the x-axis with y=0. Are you asking for how the Sun's position changes with time wrt the Galactic centre?

Comment: There is a comprehensive article at the following [link](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2002P&SS...50..217F).  Make sure to get the erratum as well, as there were a few typos in the original published version.

Comment: There is also the [HORIZONS](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) web interface at JPL.